# 2D Digital Signal Processing - Applying High Pass on and Image

Tags: image-processing, filters, lowpass-filter, digital, butterworth

I have been doing my research on 2D digital signal processing. What I am doing is about noise removal of digital image:

Type of noise that I want to remove from an images is like the Gaussian noise and 'salt and pepper'. For your information, I intend to use the butterworth lowpass filter to remove the noise. This is my code that I used in matlab.

Function Highpass

```
function [ out ] = butterhp( im,d,n )
%UNTITLED Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
h=size(im,1);
w=size(im,2);
[x,y]=meshgrid(-floor(w/2):floor(w-1)/2); -floor(h/2):floor(h-1)/2;
out= 1./(1.+(d./(x.^2+y.^2).^0.5).^(2*n));
 end
```

Function Lowpass

```
function [ out] = butterlp( im,d,n)
%UNTITLED Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
out=1-butterhp(im,d,n);
end
```

matlab code

```
a = imread('penang.jpg')
f = rgb2gray(a);
k = imnoise(f,'gaussian')
lp=butterlp(k,15,1);
af=fftshift(fft2(k));
aflp=af.*lp;
aflpi=ifft2(aflp)
noise = uint8(real(aflpi));
imshow(noise)
```

This is the image that i used.
[image: input image]

And running the code, this is what I get.

[image]

So,my problem is when I try to filter it to make it looks more clear by adjusting the number of 'n-th order' and 'cutoff frequency', it seems it does not work. It still gives me blur picture just like that.

Comment: Can't you use Median filter? Its best for salt and pepper noise

Comment: Actually, very interesting result :-).

Comment: actually,my research is about using butterworth low pass filter to remove noise. So, i am trying to make some code of butterworth low pass filter to remove this type of noise.

Comment: Why would you use such filter for Denoising of images?

Answer (score 1):

First things first: If you use `fftshift`, you have to undo it before doing the ifft. Try

```
af=fftshift(fft2(k));
aflp=af.*lp;
aflpi=ifft2(ifftshift(aflp))
```

The result should improve, especially this checkerboard-overlay should go away.

Comment: i try using your suggestion but there is nothing come out. I put the code, then i use "imshow (aflpi)", only white output come out. Can you point out what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Check your image. Is it really one value everywhere? Is `imshow` the problem, i.e. you tried `imshow(..., [])` or any boundary values instead of []? Have you tried to use `abs()` instead of `real()`?

Comment: Yes, use of `fftshift` in the middle there would explain the oscillating noise.

Comment: @PeterK. `fftshift` translates everything by N/2, which is a steep linear phase in the conjugated space. And since he is taking the real part, half of the signal is in the imaginary part. So I am quite certain that this is - at least one of - the problem(s).

Comment: @M529 : We are in violent agreement, then!

Comment: Thanks gentleman. I fix the code base on your suggestion and it works. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user18199 Glad to hear that! :)